# Does this patent not encompass the sale and use of the vast majority of cognition supplements on the market?

Tags: ca2905903a1, nootropics, cognition, supplements

In reference to the patent: [CA2905903A1](https://www.google.com/patents/CA2905903A1)

Does this patent mean any and all supplements with any combination of the listed ingredients sold with the intention of improving cognition must be given permission to be used/marketed?

It seems like absolute blanket coverage of any ingredient or combination supplement that has been shown to, or even rumoured to, improve cognition in any way. How was this allowed?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, this is an application. Claims in applications are often wildly broader than the resultant patent. Looking at the first claim, only supplements with a combination of ingredients from a), b), and c) simultaneously would potentially be covered. For example, a supplement with an item from a) and c) but not b) is free and clear. For the record, I am not a lawyer but I do have many patents.